# iterate over record in generic list

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, ienumerable

I have a list and I have a it returning just one record from that list using linq, what I am trying to do is iterate over that one record returned so I cast the returned sublist into IEnumerable, but the foreach statement I have only happens once and when I debug I obviously see that the IEnumerable has one index, but several properties and that's what values I am trying to change

example:

Edit:

```
var mylist =MyList.Where(d=>d.Field).First();
foreach( var record in mylist)
{
   foreach( var property in record)
   {
      property=value
   }
   property =value; //this only have to one property in the record
   //bascailly I want to iterate over the nested list in the list
   //essentially every index in the main list is a list itself and
   //I am trying to iterate over that indexed list
}
```

now I am running into a compile issue stating that myList doesn't contain a public definition for GetEnumerator and I cant simply cast the list to IEnumerable

EDIT 2-

sorry for the confusion, it was never a list. It was an IQuerable of objects is what mylist turns out to be, I was looking at the code run the whole time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was able to do it:

```
 var mylist =(MYOBJECT)(MyList.Where(d=>d.Field).SingleorDefault());
 PropertyInfo[] myproperties = mylist.GetType().GetProperties();
 foreach( var record in myproperties) { 

      if(record.Name==target) //target is the passed string
 }
```

Comment: Why not use the loop variable name `property` instead of `record`? Seems less confusing.

Comment: Refer to the documentation of System.Type.GetProperty which is currently at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx - it retrieves a property by name, avoiding the need to loop manually. You must then use `property.GetValue` or `property.SetValue` to get or set the property value.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 foreach because you have a `List<List<>>` don't you?

```
foreach(var element in MyList)
{

    foreach(var property in element)
    {
       //do your thing
    }
}
```

But you were only selecting the `First` element on `MyList`

Comment: now I am running into a compile issue stating that myList doesn't contain a public definition for GetEnumerator and I cant simply cast the list to IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one item, why do you need to "loop over" it?

```
var myItem = MyList.Where(d=>d.Field).First();
```

Now that's just an item, not an `IEnumerable`.

What type is the item? Is it just some class with properties? If you want to loop through those you'd need to use reflection.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear but myItem returns an index within that list. Which that index is a list itself of records and that what I want to loop though. the item is a class with properties

Comment: What are the properties of that class? Is there a property that contains the sub-list?

Comment: @Jake I suggest that you draw a nice ASCII picture of your data structure and post it to your question because it's difficult to follow your question. What do you mean by `Which that index is a list itself of records`?

Comment: imagine a gridview and I am trying to update that record/row of data in a List based on the edit in the gridview

Comment: @Jake - okay, I'm imagining that, and it's working perfectly. What's the problem?

Comment: a better example is essentially a dataset that represents a list, so imagine a DB table that I converted to a list and I want to iterate through one row of that table comparing column names, but on a list

Comment: Yes but what is the type of the items on the list? As I ask above, "What type is the item?" Edit your question to include the source code that declares the class for the items on the list.

Comment: The type of the items is IQueryable? That is, you carried out multiple queries and put them on a list?

Comment: no sorry I updated my answer, The the myList variable aover reuturns an IQueryable<t> of objects, but by using first It will only return one object and I want to update certain properties on that object

Comment: I thought so. Could you describe type of the items stored in that `IQueryable`? That is what I've been asking you all along. It is impossible to help you without that information.

Comment: the items are a class I created with properties

Comment: Okay, so there is no direct way in C# to loop through the properties of an object. This is what I meant by "you'd need to use reflection". Are all the properties of the same type? e.g. are they all `string` properties?

Comment: different types. after some trouble shooting I think I can use the getproperties for the GetType and store it in a non generic list and iterate through that. wouldnt that work?

Comment: Yes, that's called reflection. You don't need to copy the information into a list. You can loop directly: `foreach (var prop in myItem.GetType().GetProperties())` The problem is that you will have to deal with each property differently depending on its type. What are you planning to do with each property?

Comment: I am comparing it to the selected index column from my gridview so I know which value to update

Comment: I just posted an answer to do it, but it seems overkill to loop through every property, is their a faster way?

Comment: I will comment under your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding this is your scenario list nested within a list.  You are selecting one item in the parten list using some criteria and wish to set a property on all of the sub items of that item in the main list.  If so the following maps you your scenario

```
class B
    {
        public int x;
    }
    class A
    {

        public int b;
        public List<B> lst = new List<B>();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<B> Sub = new List<B>() { new B { x = 2 }, new B { x = 3 } };
        List<B> Sub2 = new List<B>() { new B { x = 4 }, new B { x = 6 } };
        List<A> Main = new List<A>() { new A() {b =2, lst = Sub2 }, new A() {b=3 , lst = Sub  } };

        var newlst = Main.Where((x) => x.b == 2).First().lst.Select((y)=> {y.x = 5;return y;});

        foreach (var item in newlst)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A.lst(x).x = {0}", item.x);
        }



    }
```

Comment: well your list is set up like a linked list, but mine is essentially a dataset that represents a list, so imagine a DB table that I converted to a list and I want to iterate through one row of that table comparing column names, but on a list

Comment: List is an indexable item not a linked list.  So does items in list A contain ID to List B Which is also a list.

Comment: sorry the list is IQueryable objects